# print div in chrome with css not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am using window.print(); for print specific part on web page, its working on firefox browser but not working correctly in Chrome it showing me blank print preview.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function printDiv() {
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById('table');
    var htmlToPrint = '' +
        '<link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />'+
        '<link href="../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#customers').dataTable();
        } );
    htmlToPrint += divToPrint.outerHTML;
    newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
}
    </script>
```

the above code was working fine in chrome also but from last 15 days it's not working in chrome but working in firefox

Comment: Maybe this is a problem with chrome 50 version, I had also problem with the new version. what is you version?

Comment: my chrome Version 50.0.2661.87 m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following code work for me fine

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btnPrint").click(function () {
                var contents = $("#table").html();
                var frame1 = $('<iframe />');
                frame1[0].name = "frame1";
                frame1.css({ "position": "absolute", "top": "-1000000px" });
                $("body").append(frame1);
                var frameDoc = frame1[0].contentWindow ? frame1[0].contentWindow : frame1[0].contentDocument.document ? frame1[0].contentDocument.document : frame1[0].contentDocument;
                frameDoc.document.open();
                //Create a new HTML document.
                frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
                frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
                //Append the external CSS file.
                frameDoc.document.write('<link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
                frameDoc.document.write('<link href="../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
                //Append the DIV contents.
                frameDoc.document.write(contents);
                frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
                frameDoc.document.close();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    window.frames["frame1"].focus();
                    window.frames["frame1"].print();
                    frame1.remove();
                }, 500);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, where I wanted to print a created window with given css, but the css would not apply in chrome.

It turns out, that we need to wait until the created window has loaded, before we try to print it (found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25396932/13294887).
Basically by using

```
myWindow.onload = function() { 
  myWindow.print(); 
  myWindow.close();
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/quoritius/qx2ujtby/21/